# A python package with static file dependency fails to read static file when used within Pyspark

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark

I am trying to resolve an issue with python packages PySpark. I developed a python package which has the following structure.

```
sample_package/
  |-config/
       |-sample.ini
  |-main.py
  |-__init__.py
```

Inside my `main.py`, I have a code snippet that reads the config file from the `config/` directory as follows

```
import ConfigParser, os
def sample_func():
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    configfile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config', 'sample.ini')
    config.read(configfile)
    return config.sections()
```

I created a zip file of the above package as `sample_package.zip` and included the zip as a pyspark dependency

`addPyFile(path/to/zip/file)`

In my pyspark job when i import the `sample_package` the import works fine and i'm able to call the `sample_func` inside main, but however my python package is unable to read the `sample.ini` file. When executed inside a plain python program, it works fine but not inside a pyspark job. Is there any path manipulation being done in a pyspark environment when accessing static files? How can I get my python package to properly read the config file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer by myself. It is more of a python packaging issue rather than pyspark environment issue. Looks like I had to use `pkgutil` module to reference my static resources which modifies my function as below

```
import ConfigParser, os, pkgutil, StringIO
def sample_func():
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    configfile = pkgutil.get_data('sample_package', 'config/sample.ini')
    cf_buf = StringIO.StringIO(configfile)
    config.readfp(cf_buf)
    return config.sections()
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple version:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import pkgutil

def sample_func():
    config = ConfigParser()
    # os.path.join is not needed.
    config_data = pkgutil.get_data(__name__, 'config/sample.ini').decode()
    config.read_string(config_data)
    return config.sections()
```